# Barter system data type

Tags: data-structure

My game has 4 supplies, `Gold Wheat Iron Fuel`, a player is allowed to select a supply to trade and what supply to receive from merchant NPCs.

Currently, when the user trades an item I have the following logic
I am using c# but this is not the exact code used.

```
if(sellGold){
    if(buyGold){
        tradeRatio = .5;
    }
    if(buyWheat){
        tradeRatio = 3;
    }
}
else if(sellIron){
    if(buyGold){
        tradeRatio = 1;
    }
    if(buyFuel){
        tradeRatio = 2;
    }
}
...etc
```

Where the amount a player receives is calculated by multiplying the trade ratio by the amount sold.

This works, it is just rather tedious and would be a pain to add more supplies later. What would a better approach be? I'm thinking of assigning each item a value and that value is different based on the trade type, but that still involves a whole bunch of nested conditionals.

Comment: What programming language are you working with? My first thought is you could make this easier using a new `Enum` type, but what you can and cannot do with Enum's will depend a lot on the programming language.

Comment: @Sys_Admin_Luddite c# edited the question to include that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be much easier if you use [currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency) to express all prices. It doesn't have to appear in game, just something used to express the underlying value of all these supplies. Then add a buy/sell offset (or [spread](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/spread.asp)). Trade ratios can be calculated by dividing those prices.

For example, if we have `goldBid = 1.23`, `goldAsk = 1.25`, `wheatBid = 0.34`, `wheatAsk = 0.38`, then selling 1 gold for wheat gives you `1.23 / 0.38 = 3.23` wheat, and doing the reverse (selling 1 wheat for gold) gives you `0.34 / 1.25 = 0.27` gold.

Using a currency is not only simpler, it helps you avoid pricing mistakes that inadvertantly lead to *negative cycles* that can be arbitraged (a.k.a. "free money"). For example, what happens if you can trade 1 gold for 2 wheat, and 1 wheat for 2 gold?

But if you want to express all your prices manually, as is often the case in inefficient markets, the usual representation is a [weighted directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), where edge weights represent trade prices. But a simpler representation would be a *matrix*, like this one:

[image]

Then you can just read off values in the matrix to get the trade ratios. In code you can represent this as a 2D array, where the dimensions are the number of assets you have.

Comment: Using a matrix (either 2D array or nested dictionaries) would also allow you to define these values external to the game, like in a data file. This means you can make changes without a recompile (Or allow users to add new resources and/or exchange rates for modding).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll use the currency with Bid and Ask prices. I do like the Pokemon matrix though

Comment: FYI the matrix is definitely more flexible, for example you can set up a situation where it's cheaper to trade A -> B -> C than A -> C (imagine if the wheat seller *really* doesn't want to buy gold). Depends on whether you want that extra game mechanic.